# Erlang File Append mode

Tags: erlang

I m trying to write some content in file using append mode in erlang but it giving error as bad argument.

```
Syntax used: file:write_file("/tmp/test1.txt","Abhimanyu","append").
error:{error,badarg}
```

thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the "don't create it if it doesn't exist" additional question, you have to be more creative by using something like file:read_file_info :

```
 case file:read_file_info(FileName) of
        {ok, FileInfo} ->
                 file:write_file(FileName, "Abhimanyu", [append]);
        {error, enoent} ->
                 % File doesn't exist
                 donothing
 end.
```

The append mode (or write mode) will create the file if it doesn't exist...

Answer (score 18):

The `file:write_file` function expects the last argument to be a list of [atoms](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#2.3) iso a string so changing your implementation to `file:write_file("/tmp/test1.txt","Abhimanyu", [append]).` should resolve your issue. Further examples can be found at [TrapExit](http://www.trapexit.org/Category:FileRecipes).

Comment: Thanx for the help...one more thing i wanna know it wont create the file ..if it dodesnt exists.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you need:

```
file:write_file("/tmp/test1.txt", "Abhimanyu", [append]).
```

I think you may also need to convert your data to a binary.