# How do I write output to a text file without overriding the existing contents of the file?

Tags: file-io, erlang

I have developed this function which transfers data from `erlang` to a `.txt` file:

```
exporttxt()->

F1 ="1",
F2 = "afif",
F3 = "kaled",

file:write_file("test.txt",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2,F3])] ).
```

After running this function `test.txt` contains these values:

`"1"  "afif" "kaled"`

but when I change `F1`, `F2` and `F3` in the function `exporttxt()` to:

```
F1 ="2"
F2 ="ahmed"
F3 = "alagi"
```

then `test.txt`contains just these values:

`"2"   "ahmed"  "alagi"`

and I want `test.txt` to contain:

```
"1"  "afif"  "kaled"
"2"  "ahmed" "alagi"
```

The problem is that at each execution of the function it records the new data
and the old data in `test.txt` is deleted.

How can I write new data to `test.txt` without overwriting existing data?

Comment: You are looking for append: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067617/erlang-file-append-mode

Answer (score 4):

Use [file:write_file/3](http://erldocs.com/R14B02/kernel/file.html?i=2&search=file%3awri#write_file/3) for this point:

Third arguments is `Modes`. A list of possible modes is read `| write | append | exclusive | raw | binary | {delayed_write, Size, Delay} | delayed_write | {read_ahead, Size} | read_ahead | compressed | {encoding, Encoding}`. `append` mode is for your needs.